# Upgrading BlueZ failes with: Install GLib >= 2.28 is required

Tags: bluetooth, 21.10, glibc, bluez

I'm trying to connect my Keychron K3 keyboard with my PC via bluetooth, but the keyboard is not listed. So I've tried it on my office laptop there it works.

Both devices running Ubuntu 21.10 with kernel 5.13, the only difference is, that my laptop runs with BlueZ 5.6 and my PC with version 5.56. So I decided to upgrade.

I've downloaded BlueZ 5.62 and tried to run `./configure` but the following error has occurred:

```
checking for glib-2.0 >= 2.28... no
configure: error: GLib >= 2.28 is required
```

Both devices have glib 2.34 installed.

Can anyone help why I receive this error or why the bluetooth manager doesn't show the device?

Comment: Is the development package `libglib2.0-dev` installed - or just the runtime library package?

Comment: yes dev package is installed: "libglib2.0-dev is already the newest version (2.68.4-1ubuntu1)."

Comment: To ease the compilation enable source code repositories and then run `sudo apt-get build-dep bluez` . Which bluetooth manager do you use? Is it Blueman on both machines?

Comment: I've followed your instructions now I'm running on bluez 5.6. My PC used blueman. I've removed it. Now the keyboard is listed in Bluetooth > Settings. When I try to connect, it takes a while, changes the status to "not set up" and then the keyboard disappears.